# Oracle Cloud - Always Free - Can't create VCN or Compute Instance

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a Oracle Cloud Always Free Account.
I can create a database with Apex. But i am not able to create a VCN or a Compute Instance. I always get this error: **Count of total IPv6 CIDRs exceeds max limit: 0**

I tried everything, with the help of the wizards and without.
I already found the same issue on stackoverflow. But the solution didn't work for me.

Region: eu-frankfurt-1

Comment: have you enabled  IPv6 on the VCN? from oci docs "During VCN creation, you choose whether the VCN is enabled for IPv6, or you can enable IPv6 on existing IPv4-only VCNs." https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/ipv6.htm

Comment: Thx Nigel. It still doesn't work. With the option "Enable IPv6 CIDR Block" and without this option i always get the same "Count of total IPv6 CIDRs exceeds max limit: 0" error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looks like this should be fixed now.